# Giving pork gelatin candies to others

Tags: sharia, pork

Is it allowed to eat candies created with pork gelatin ?

And if a person gave it to you is it allowed to give it to someone else (non-Muslim) who can eat it?

Answer (score 1):

Eating pork in any shape and any form is prohibited in Islam. It's Haram, and you can't eat it. You should not give it to others too. The best way is to accept it with open arms if you think that he/she will get unhappy, but discard it without letting him/she know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Consuming Pork or Serving it to others is Strictly a wrong in ISLAM,

[Wikipedia Link about Eating Pork on islam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_restrictions_on_the_consumption_of_pork#Prohibition_of_pork_consumption_in_Islamic_law)

And i personally suggest you not to give it to non-muslim who eats it. Because you should give others what you love.

Answer (score 0):

When someone has food (or clothing or animals or objects) that one does not want (or cannot have for religious, moral or other reasons), then it is okay to give it to someone else who does not have the same restriction.  If there is halal food and pork on a boat, and people are starving, it is better for the pork to be given to the people who have no restrictions, than to throw it out, and risk both groups dying.

Same with an animal (snake, pig, monkey) that may be wrong for a child, a mother, etc., but okay for a scientist.